# UILabels not updating XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am very new to iOS development. I developed a code but it is not updating any labels. what I am doing wrong?
    The code is as follows. I am using storyboard, the navigation is working properly but I cannot update the UILabel.

```
//  TodayScheduleViewController.m

@interface TodayScheduleViewController ()
@end


@implementation TodayScheduleViewController

@synthesize timeNowLabel;
@synthesize timeNow;
@synthesize lampImage;
@synthesize groupSchedule;
@synthesize lightStatus;
@synthesize timeRemaining;
@synthesize dayOfWeek;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // This will pass the values of to UILabel every time the view will load


    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    self.timenowlabel.text = resultString;

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSInteger weekday = [dateComps weekday];
    if (weekday==1) {dayOfWeek = @"Sunday";}
    else if(weekday==2){dayOfWeek = @"Monday";}
    else if(weekday==3){dayOfWeek = @"Tuesday";}
    else if(weekday==4){dayOfWeek = @"Wednesday";}
    else if(weekday==5){dayOfWeek = @"Thursday";}
    else if(weekday==6){dayOfWeek = @"Friday";}
    else if(weekday==7){dayOfWeek = @"Saturday";}

    self.dayofweek.text = self.dayOfWeek;


    groupSchedule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", GroupNumber];
    self.groupschedule.text = self.groupSchedule;

    self.lightstatus.text = @"This is it";

}
```

The header file as follows:

```
@interface TodayScheduleViewController : UIViewController

// These 2 NSString objects are created because it will pass the values to the UILabels
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *timeNowLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *timeNow;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSStream *lampImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *groupSchedule;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *lightStatus;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *timeRemaining;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *dayOfWeek;

// These are the outlets of the UILabels that we want to change based on the button selected
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timenowlabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *time_now;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lampimage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *groupschedule;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lightstatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeremaining;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dayofweek;


@end
```

Comment: Are labels linked as IBOutlet in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes I have attached them by ctrl+dragging into the header file.

Comment: hm... i don't see any problem with the code provided.

Comment: IBOutlet better be weak property and NSString should defined as copy. I have upload a [sample example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fnjoh8vpktuxbm/TodayTemp.zip?dl=0) based on your code, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using breakpoints, I was able to backtrace why the `dayOfWeek` label didn't update:

`[dateComps weekday]` returned `MAX_INT` (the maximum value an NSInteger can have) instead the day of the week. That is because you have initialized your `NSDateComponents *dateComps` the wrong way:

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This is the correct way in your case.

Now try to use breakpoints to backtrace why your other labels aren't updating, because you haven't given enough code for me to do it.

Comment: Hi hoiberg42,thanks other labels are working now but it is saying calendar as undeclared

Comment: Oops, I indeed forgot to declare `calendar`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for support.
I was able to update as,

```
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    self.time.text = resultString;

/*    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSInteger weekday = [dateComps weekday];
    if (weekday==1) {self.dayofweek.text = @"Sunday";}
    else if(weekday==2){self.dayofweek.text = @"Monday";}
    else if(weekday==3){self.dayofweek.text = @"Tuesday";}
    else if(weekday==4){self.dayofweek.text = @"Wednesday";}
    else if(weekday==5){self.dayofweek.text = @"Thursday";}
    else if(weekday==6){self.dayofweek.text = @"Friday";}
    else if(weekday==7){self.dayofweek.text = @"Saturday";}*/

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEEE"];
    self.dayofweek.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
```

Thank you again.